# What should be concern when deploy an large-scale application?

Tags: mysql, laravel, scalability

I tried to set up a **micro-blog web site** with simple function.

And in the future, I would set some API for the mobile app.

The main feature is simple. People can register, post blog , tag articles, and comments.

Currently, I am using **laravel framework + Mysql + Apache** and **host on VPS**.

(Hardwere spec is HD:160 GB,CPU:8core,RAM:8 GB.)

The database tables are basic,including **user,comments,article,tags,and tags pivot table**.

Everything works fine.

But 
**I had a little concern about scalability and performance.**

Since I have no any expereince about scale a web site.

Could someone give me some key concepts of **what should I concern if the users numbers increase to 10,000 ~100,000?**

I am OK with change my host platform or even change the framework and database at the begining.

All I try to avoid is that the web site might be crash after deploy a period of time.

The update and transfer would be a disaster.Thanks

Comment: There're lots of good articles on http://highscalability.com/

Answer (score 0):

Look into scalable cloud hosting, such as digital ocean or amazon, where you can scale your capacity as you grow.

These companies allow you to start small with a "slice" of a server and as you grow you can grow into multiple servers. Load balancing is usually done on their end so all you need to do is focus on your application